# how to diselected a row in 2Darray on the basis of condition and find sum of other rows

Tags: java, arrays

i wanted to print the sum of 2Darray on the bases of condition. if a row in 2Darray conation -1 integer add the sum of row and exclude -1  integer.   else if a row in 2Darray does not conation -1  integer  skip  that row and don't add in sum

```
public class Mainclass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] places = { 
                { 2, 3, -1 }, 
                { -1, 4, 5 }, 
                { 2, 3, 4 } };

        int ch = -1, col;
        int sum = 0;

        for (int row = 0; row < places.length; row++) {
            for (col = 0; col < places[row].length; col++) {
                if (places[row][col] == ch) // skip the -1 integer in 2D array
                {
                }
                if (ch != places[row])
                // here i want to diselected the row that do not conatin -1
                // integer
                // skip row that does not contain -1
                {
                }
                sum += places[row][col];
                // print the sum of row that contain -1 and also exclude -1
                // integer in sum
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
        // and the sum should be 2+3+4+5=14
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code? Does it work? Why doesn't it work? How does conation apply here?

Comment: Have a rowTotal. Have a specialCharFound boolean. If specialCharFound add rowTotal to grandTotal.

Comment: Add sysout at various places, and try to see the flow. Else debug and step through if you're using an IDE like Eclipse.

Comment: yes specialCharFound is -1 but i don't know how to to apply the condition and exlcude specialCharFound -1 in sum . how to diselected row in 2Darray

Answer (score 1):

In case of -1 that can appear only once that will work:

```
int [][] places = {
        {2,3,-1},
        {-1,4,5},
        {2,3,4}
};

int sum=0;
for(int row=0;row<places.length;row++)
{
    if(Arrays.stream(places[row]).filter(x->x==-1).findAny().isPresent()){
        sum+=Arrays.stream(places[row]).sum()+1;
    }

}
```

output:

> 14

Comment: Nice way but You need to explain your solution not just throw it . (upvote anyway)

Comment: Thank you
I hope to add explanations and perhaps a general case, do note is iterate twice over  places[row] array so performance way it's not the best solution

Answer (score 0):

You may compute a temporary sum for each row, that you will only add to the final sum is there was no `-1` .

See this example with some comments :

```
   public static void main(final String args[]) throws IOException, ParseException {

        int[][] places = {
                { 2, 3, -1 },
                { -1, 4, 5 },
                { 2, 3, 4 }
        };

        int ch = -1, col;
        int sum = 0;
        for (int[] place : places) {

            int tempSum = 0; // sum of the current row only

            boolean containsMinusOne = false;

            for (col = 0; col < place.length; col++) {
                if (place[col] == ch) // skip the -1 integer in 2D array
                {
                    containsMinusOne = true;
                    continue; // skip the rest of this iteration, -1 won't be added to the temp sum below.
                }

                tempSum += place[col];

            }

            // if there was a -1, add the sum of this row
            if (containsMinusOne) {

                sum += tempSum;
            }

        }
        System.out.println(sum);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What about just use simple `for...each`? Seems to me it looks pretty simple and clear:

```
public static long sum(int[][] places) {
    long res = 0;

    for (int[] row : places) {
        int sum = 0;
        boolean apply = false;

        for (int col : row) {
            if (col != -1)
                sum += col;
            else
                apply = true;
        }

        res += apply ? sum : 0;
    }

    return res;
}
```

***Example:***

```
int[][] places = { { 2, 3, -1 }, { -1, 4, 5 }, { 2, 3, 4 } };
System.out.println(sum(places));    // 14
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution can be direct, finding row sum and keeping a boolean variable which checks if the row contains -1 or not.

if the value of the boolean variable is true, we add the row sum to the total, else skip it.

```
int [][] places = {
                {2,3,-1},
                {-1,4,5},
                {2,3,-1}
                };

int ch=-1,col;
int sum=0;
for(int row=0;row<places.length;row++)
{
        boolean rowCheck = false;
        int rowSum=0;
        for( col=0;col<places[row].length;col++)
        {
        rowSum+=places[row][col];
// print the sum of row that contain -1 and also  exclude -1 integer in sum

        if(places[row][col]==ch) // skip the -1 integer in 2D array
        {
         rowCheck=true;
         rowSum+=1;
         }
    }
    if(rowCheck)
        sum+=rowSum; 
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Stream api solution which is quite intuitive.

```
Arrays
    .stream(places)
    .filter(row -> Arrays.stream(row).anyMatch(x -> x == ch))
    .mapToInt(row -> Arrays.stream(row).filter(x -> x != ch).sum())
    .sum()
```

1. Present the matrix into a stream of integer arrays.
2. Filter any of the arrays that doesn't contain the special character.
3. Filter the special characters in the particular integer array and sum all the other elements, return the sum to the outer stream.
4. Sum up all the returned sums.